# Upload image to database in laravel 5 using eloquent ORM?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have one form which contains one file upload.

Form Id is "upload_form"

```
<input type="file" id="image" name="image"/>
```

Using javascript onclick function and ajax to pass the image to the controller.

Ajax fn:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'UploadImage',
data:new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
type: "post",
dataType:"JSON",
async:false,

success: function (data) {

console.log(data);

      }
});
}
```

Routes:

```
Routes::post('UploadImage','UploadController@Upload');
```

UploadController:

```
public function Upload()
{
 $file = Input::file('image');
 $tmpFilePath = '/temp/uploads/';
 $tmpFileName = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
 $path = $tmpFilePath.$tmpFileName;
 $data_file = $file->move(public_path() . $tmpFilePath, $tmpFileName);
 // Error for move() and getClientOriginalName() functions.

}
```

Comment: so what is the issue ???

Comment: I tried to save the image in temporary file and its not working.

Comment: @Sunil Try this one http://pastebin.com/P4tGNd09. If it doesn't work, check your write permissions

Comment: @GONG I am also try do the same but the error coming for 'function move()' and also getClientOriginalName() is also not accepting.

Comment: @Sunil try to put enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form

Comment: @GONG Yeah i will try that. Thank you. But i want to make this change in ajax function? because data is passing through ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @GONG. 
Changed my form to this. Worked.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload_form" role="form" method="POST" action="" >
```

Answer (score 2):

use this and it should work for you ... :)

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

     {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="file" id="image" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
 </form>
```